# cordova app not running in avd

Tags: android, cordova

My cordova app is giving me the error: connection to server was unsuccessful.(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)  on an android avd.It runs fine on my device but i wanted to test different android platforms.please help.

Comment: should be: file:///android_asset/www/index.html, not the 3 /'s

Comment: Thanks for that pointer i edited accordingly in the question i just.asked